# inserting remote image onto windows form in vb.net?

Tags: vb.net

anyone have experience doing this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What do you mean with remote? If you mean an image residing on a web server you can do like this:

```
Dim client As New System.Net.WebClient()
Dim stream As New System.IO.MemoryStream()
Dim data As Byte() = client.DownloadData("http://somewebsite/someimage.jpg")
client.Dispose()
stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length)
pictureBox.Image = Image.FromStream(stream)
```

**Update**

Marcs comment about rewinding the stream sparked my curiosity, so I looked into it, and thought I would add it here for completeness.

After writing the data to the stream, the stream's position will be pointing at the end of the stream and before reading from the stream, you would normally need to set the position to the beginning of the stream (`stream.Position = 0`). As it turns out, `Image.FromStream` will do this internally, and restore the stream position after loading the image.

Comment: You probably need to rewind the stream between the write and the read - or alternatively, use the MemoryStream ctor that accepts a byte[]

Comment: cool! what do i have to import to be able to use system.net.webclient?>

Comment: marc - can you please elaborate, im a beginner so i dont know what you mean

Comment: @Marc: I thought that too, but tested the code before posting and there was no problem with it. Surprised me a bit, honestly.

Comment: @alex: WebClient is in the System assembly that should be automatically referenced when creating a new project. It is in the System.Net namespace; if you use the code as in my sample no Imports are necessary. If you add Imports System.Net, you can of course leave out the System.Net part when creating the WebClient instance.

Comment: actually i did have to set the position to 0 when i was inserting multiple image in the same stream